# getAttribute for Multiple images

Tags: jquery

How getAttribute will work for Multiple images?
Can any one heip pls?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".img").click(function(){   
      var img = $(this).getAttribute('src');
      alert(img.getAttribute('src')); // foo.jpg
      alert(img.src);                 // http://..../foo.jpg
    });
  });
</script>

</head>
  <body>
    <img class="img" src="foo.jpg" >
    <img class="img" src="foo1.jpg" >
    <img class="img" src="foo2.jpg" >
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: use jQuery's `.attr()` to get an element's attribute, or break out of jQuery before using native methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yoo need to convert jquery object to plain javascript object to use its native methods and properties. You already have that object in `this` context. Thus, Use:

```
$(".img").click(function(){   
  this.getAttribute('src'); // when using with jquery $(this)[0].getAttribute('src')
});
```

Comment: `$(this)[0].getAttribute('src')` is, ahem, the opposite of smart. Use `this.src` or `$(this).attr('src')` if you really want a `$`.

Comment: @dystroy: i was editing that only. making jquery object from js object and then again reverting back is worthless :)

Comment: `$(this).attr("src")` is what you should be using. It's not evil to be flip-floppity between native DOM and jQuery, but you're gonna end up confusing a newbie.

Comment: @NickDugger Why not `this.src` ?

Comment: And why the downvote for?? help me improvising the answer by letting me know whats the fault.

Comment: @dystroy Nothing wrong with this.src, but if I'm going to give a jQuery answer, I'd make it all jQuery. You never know the level of the questioner and their ability to confuse themselves (as the questioner does above: `$(this).getAttribute('src');`)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want!
Just get them all:

```
$(".img").each(function(){
    alert(this.getAttribute("src"));
});
```

Or in your sample code:

```
$(".img").click(function(){   
  var img = this.getAttribute('src');
});
```

Finally, you can use the .attr();

```
   $(".img").each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("src"));
    });
```